# How Can I Intercept Exec Calls in Linux?

Tags: linux, exec

**tl;dr:** I'm hoping to wrap all application executions with something that checks Caps Lock, and depending on its state, either let's the application pass through as normal, or pass the executable (and its env and args) to another app.

**Long Story:** I have an Optimus laptop and want a trivial way, that involves the least amount of work from a UX standpoint, to tell an application to use either the Intel graphics, or the Nvidia GPU.

I actually have a (very rough) working prototype here:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -z `xset q | grep -o 'Caps Lock:   on'` ]]; then
    notify-send -u low -t 5000 -a 'Steam' -i 'steam' -c game 'Steam' 'GPU: intel'
    steam
else
    notify-send -u low -t 5000 -a 'Steam' -i 'steam' -c game 'Steam' 'GPU: nvidia'
    primusrun steam
fi
```

But, even if I generalized this by using `$0`, symlinks, and other fun shell magic, this isn't sufficient for all scenarios. Some apps appear to fork in ways that prevent `primusrun` (and what it puts in the env) from following the entire execution chain. I currently get around this by executing a shell `primusrun xfce4-terminal`, and then executing those apps from there. (Even this, though, fails when an app uses a daemon process to execute apps, separate from whatever I'm executing. In these cases, I have to restart those daemon's with `primusrun`... which I really dislike doing.)

If I were to do it without help, I would use `LD_PRELOAD` to hijack low-level calls to exec* to inject my wrapper. Which sounds like a lot of work for something that you clever people probably know of better ways of doing. ;)